# Lua - nil value error

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, adc

I get the following error message from nodeMCU on esp8266 :
    **attempt to call field "adc.force_init_mode" (a nil value).**
Can somebody point out the mistake please?

```
if adc.force_init_mode(adc.INIT_ADC) 
  then
    node.restart()
  return
end
val = adc.read(0)
print("Input number:", val )
val2 = 5000000 - (val*5000000/1023)
print("R (ohm):", val2 )
```

Comment: Do you have a `adc = require 'adc'` anywhere?

Comment: If it's possible, put it _before_ the snippet you provided.

Comment: Do you need any more info? If not, consider [accepting (and/or upvoting) the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that SO can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your firmware does either not have the ADC module compiled in or it's got an ADC module without the `force_init_mode` function.

Therefore, [build](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/) a recent firmware and [flash it to upgrade](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/#upgrading-firmware) your current firmware.

Comment: wouldn't you get an error for indexing adc then? adc obviously is a table in his version.
Maybe some old version of the adc module that does not implement force_init_mode? Fix is the same of course.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt the error message in the description above is 100% accurate. `http.foo()` yields "attempt to call field 'foo'..." while `bar.foo()` yields "attempt to index global 'bar'". Note that in the OP's question it says "...field 'adc.force_init_mode'" (extra 'adc.'). I'll update the answer anyway.

Comment: oh totally missed that :)

Comment: Thank you! I have problem in uploading built firmware...I'm working on that!